# my app does not show in google play after 2 day

Tags: android, google-play, publish

My application was published on the Google Play Store but did not appear with my apps or through the search .

https://play.google.com/store/apps/developer?id=Team-L

However, it appears when I search by package

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.teaml.cookingapp

please anyone help me .

Comment: Use proper words. When you say "it doesn't appear" it conveys your app is not published.

Comment: The search problem may be because the application name is not English. Try reporting it to Google. It is however visible in the developer's page. Also change "fix bugs" to "Fixed bugs" of "bug fixes" in what's new section eventhough it has nothing to do with search results.

Comment: Thanks for your help

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272165/are-developer-centric-questions-about-application-stores-on-topic

Answer (score 1):

Hi when you query like this "https://play.google.com/store/apps/developer?id=Team-L" you are searching for the package not exactly the app. So play store will show all the applications with that id. And when you query this "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.teaml.cookingapp", you are actually searching your application. 
Hope it solves your doubt.

Comment: when i query "https://play.google.com/store/apps/developer?id=Team-L"  should show all my app so why this app does not appear with other my apps Although it for the same developer